# amplify.js pub/sub Synchronous or Asynchronous?

Tags: javascript

Are amplify.js's pub/sub events implemented as Synchronous or Asynchronous?

http://amplifyjs.com/api/pubsub/

The documentation does mention priorities...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Publishing is synchronous; prioritization and synchronicity aren't really related.

Answer (score 4):

It's synchronous.

The subscription callbacks are called from within the `.publish()` method's implementation.  There is no `setTimeout()` code.

As far as priorities go, `priority` determines where to inject the callback in the callback stack.  This logic is handled in `.subscribe()`.  The `.publish()` method just executes the callbacks in stack order as previously determined by the `.subscribe()` method.